# g-places-autocomplete not working on android build

Tags: ionic-framework, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am creating app on ionic and used g-places-autocomplete for google place auto complete.

It works well on browser, but not working on app after I built it on android app via `ionic build android` command.

Comment: can you provide with some code for reference?

Comment: Hello @sam, thanks for your reply.
Below is HTML code
===
<md-input-container class="full-width custom-input no-margin" >
      <input type="text" name="location" autocomplete="off" id="location" ng-model="vm.location" g-places-autocomplete />
    </md-input-container>
===
It works perfectly on browser in desktop and mobile. But it not works after i build app of android.

Comment: are you sure you are passing argument libraries=places `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&libraries=places`and installed `cordova whitelist plugin`

Comment: Hello @sam, Yes , i am passing argument libraries in googleapi URL. Also i have installed whitelist plugin. Also in my config.xml there is <allow-navigation href="*" />.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug with android test app, i got error that i have not add Referrer URL as per android strucuture which is "**file_url**//android_asset/XXXXX".

After i added above type of URL, it start working.